# USB Wireless keyboard not working during bootup

Tags: windows-7, usb, wireless-keyboard

During boot, my wireless USB keyboard doesn't work. Other USB corded keyboards work, so I know USB is enabled in my BIOS. This is a bit annoying because it makes it impossible to enter setup, choose boot OS, etc before Windows starts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you 100 % sure 'USB Legacy Support' is enabled in the BIOS? not just an assumption based on the fact that 'corded keyboards' work?

Comment: @Molly, I had a similar problem that was fixed by exactly what you suggested.  I had other keyboards that worked, but the wireless wouldn't until I enabled the USB legacy support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you check all settings in the BIOS that can possibly affect the keyboard. One of those may control it. On the other hand, it may be that the keyboard refuses to work in the BIOS because it was created that way. Or the USB port isn't getting enough power on boot to recognize the keyboard in time. Since non-wireless keyboards work, I would try another wireless keyboard, if you can buy from a retailer with a nice return policy.

Because different manufacturers have different ways to make wireless work, you may be best off contacting them if none of your troubleshooting works.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally 2 solutions for this if you want to avoid purchasing a wired keyboard:

- Buy a [USB to PS/2 adapter](http://www.tigerdirect.ca/applications/SearchTools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=2380045&CatId=469), they are fairly cheap:

[image]

- Check your BIOS, newer ones usually have a "Wireless detection" feature which will look for these devices on boot. Regularly though the drivers aren't loaded until Windows starts which is why you don't get response at boot.

Comment: Problem with this answer is that often the PS/2 adapters remove some of the keyboard's functionality.

Comment: I'm sure it wont stop him from using function keys on boot and the arrow keys in BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran into an odd situation with a wireless keyboard that may relate to your issue. My BIOS and pre-OS bootup options wouldn't recognize the keyboard commands until the mouse moved.
So, for example, I'd hit DEL to go into setup and then move my mouse and it would recognize the command.
In the BIOS I'd hit the down arrow but the cursor wouldn't move until I twitched the mouse. It still does it even though I've switched mice so I'm positive it's the keyboard and nothing I do in the BIOS makes it work any better - and I really haven't worried about it enough to track it down any further. I just remember to keep twitching the mouse as I select items in BIOS or choose which OS to boot from the GRUB boot up menu and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Plug your wireless keyboard receiver into a USB 2.0 port, not a USB 3.0 port. USB 2.0 ports are usually black while USB 3.0 ports are blue. If you have a USB 2.0 port near the PS/2 keyboard port, use that one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. @JoshuaNurczyk answer helped me.

1. I couldn't use my wireless keyboard to choose item in a Windows boot menu.
2. I could enter `BIOS` setup and use my keyboard there.
3. I could use the keyboard in the Windows GUI.

I just checked USB options in my `BIOS` setup and figured out that `Use USB keyboard` option is disabled. I just enabled it. And that fixed the problem with a Windows boot menu.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no difference between cordless or Wireless USB keyboards, they use the same serial protocol. I suggest tying another USB port, if you are using a desktop PC , try the nearest ones.